# Java - creating a triangle with numbers using nested for-loops

Tags: java, for-loop

I have homework to make a triangle that looks like this:

```
          1
        2 1 2
      3 2 1 2 3
    4 3 2 1 2 3 4 
  5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5
6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I have been able to create almost half the triangle with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

            for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
              for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                System.out.print(j + " ");
              System.out.println();
            }
}
```

I have been unable to figure out how to mirror the other half of the triangle with my code to look like the triangle above. The instructor hinted that using the for loop with the tab return `\t` is the way to do this.

Comment: `for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                System.out.print(j + " ");`  Tip: For clarity, change every loop to something like `for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) { 
                System.out.print(j + " "); }` (add braces even for a single-line loop).

Comment: i want you to try it out first as you are in a learning phase , i will just give you a hint that print decreasing no of spaces in every line , now give it a try , then we'll help you after that

Answer (score 2):

try

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 6; j > i; j--) {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }
        for (int j = i; j > 1; j--) {
            System.out.print(j + " ");
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(j + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

output

```
          1 
        2 1 2 
      3 2 1 2 3 
    4 3 2 1 2 3 4 
  5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 
6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: Okay I see!! This is a great help - I was about at my wits end. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Print 2*(6-i) spaces, then print numbers from j = i descending while j > 0, then print numbers from j = 2 ascending while j <= i.